# C++ object/class instance used in boolean expression

Tags: c++, class

I am learning the specifics of C++ while trying to read and parse some FLAC source code (I presently only know Java and C#), and I've come upon this:

```
class OurDecoder: public FLAC::Decoder::File {
public:
  OurDecoder(FILE *f_): FLAC::Decoder::File(), f(f_) { }
protected:
  FILE *f;
  ...
};

OurDecoder decoder(fout);

if(!decoder) {
  fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: allocating decoder\n");
  fclose(fout);
  return 1;
}
```

I understand that the line `OurDecoder decoder(fout);` is creating a new instance of the `OurDecoder` class and calling it `decoder`. This would be (sort of) equivalent to the Java syntax `OurDecoder decoder = new OurDecoder(fout);`, except that if I understand correctly, this specific syntax allocates the object on the stack instead of in the Heap. But anyhow, that's not my issue..

What I'm very curious about (and I've never seen anything like it before) is the statement `if(!decoder)`. What is going on under the hood here? Is this akin to Java's `if (decoder == null)`?

Comment: `decoder` cannot be null. `operator!` has been overloaded to provide status info.

Answer (score 5):

It means that either `OurDecoder` or the base class `FLAC::Decoder::File` has either:

- overloaded `operator!()` or
- provided a conversion operator, such as `operator bool()`, to convert to some type which can be used as an operand to the built-in `!` operator

Consult the class definitions or documentation to find the operator, and exactly what it means. Conventionally, `!object` should indicate that the object is invalid, empty, or otherwise unusable in some way.

It's not equivalent to Java's check for a null reference; this is an object, not a reference or pointer, and there's no such thing as a null object in C++.

Comment: Theoretically, it could also mean that the fragment is dead code and never gets executed. But Lilshieste's answer is more specific and should be pursued.

Comment: @MKaama: Unless it's in a template that's never instantiated, then it would still get compiled, and so a valid operator or conversion sequence would have to exist even if it's never executed.

Answer (score 4):

According to this [FLAC API documentation](http://xiph.org/flac/api/classFLAC_1_1Decoder_1_1Stream.html#FLAC_1_1Decoder_1_1Streama3), the `FLAC::Decoder::File` class (or rather its base class `FLAC::Decoder::Stream`) overloads the `operator bool()`. This allows the `decoder` instance to be implicitly converted to a boolean value.